# Rails update join table attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, join

I have User, Attachment and Form models

```
 form = @user.forms.where(attachment_id: attachment.id)
 form.update_attributes(status: "full")
```

when I try to update a join table attribute, it says

```
undefined method `update_attributes
```

in my models there are only necessary has_many or belongs to attributes. I don't understand why update_attributes does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where() returns a relation, not an individual ActiveRecord object.  If you want to update an individual form, use find_by()

```
form = @user.forms.find_by(attachment_id: attachment.id)
```